# Print list of list of integer

Tags: java

I have the following list:

```
List<List<int[]>> graph;
```

How can I print the content of graph without using loop? I tried the following 2 methods but all of them failed to print:

```
int[][] input=new int[][]{{1,2,5},{1,3,6},{2,3,1}};
List<List<int[]>> graph = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) graph.add(new ArrayList<>());
        for (int[] conn : input) {
            int city_A = conn[0], city_B = conn[1], price = conn[2];
            graph.get(city_A).add(new int[] {city_B, price});
            graph.get(city_B).add(new int[] {city_A, price});
        }
graph.forEach(s->System.out.println("Output:"+s));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(graph.toArray()));
```

> Output:[[I@1fb3ebeb, [I@548c4f57]
>   Output:[[I@1218025c, [I@816f27d]
>   Output:[[I@87aac27, [I@3e3abc88]

Expected output is to print each element without going to new line:

> Output: [[1,2], [1,3], [2,0]]

Comment: That forEach is a loop. I'm a bit confused on why you don't want a loop.

You're getting the memory addresses of the List objects. Since you have a List of Lists you'll need to go deeper with your string prints.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: Please provide sample input, ie code that initializes `graph`, and what the expected output is for that sample? That will be clearer, more illustrative for future visitors, and make it far easier for us to craft and test and answer.

Comment: Already provided more code. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: @Lemma the expected output doesn't look like it matches the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

- `graph.stream` creates a stream of `List<int[]>`
- `flatmap(List::stream)` takes those lists and creates a single stream of `int[]`
- `Arrays.toString` takes an array and prints it separated by commas.

Note that printing an array is printing an `object`.  Its default `toString` is what you see when you print it so it won't work.  `Arrays.toString()` actually iterates over each element and returns a string that is printable.

```
    List<List<int[]>> graph = some list;

    graph.stream().flatMap(List::stream)
                .forEach(arr->System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr) + " "));
```

**More on printing arrays**

Notice the numeric part (in hex) for printing out this array.  The numeric part
comes from the hashCode.  Also the `[I` in front of the first output means a simple int array. `[[I` signifies an array of int arrays.

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2};
System.out.println(arr1); // prints [I@4617c264 on my machine
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(arr1.hashCode()));

int[][] arr2 = {{1,2},{3,4}};
System.out.println(arr2); // prints [[I@36baf30c on my machine
```

Comment: Some explanation about why the arrays don't print out correctly would be nice. Try and avoid code only answers.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: the original question has changed.

I think what you actually want is a string representation of your graph.Have you tried a simple

```
System.out.println(graph);
```

?

Leaving the answer to the original question up, which was how to print all the integers in the inner list without using a traditional for loop.

```
graph.forEach(innerList -> {
    innerList.forEach(s-> System.out.println("Output: "+ s))
});
```

But why though..

Also the forEach is just the java functional library shorthand for a traditional for loop, so I'm not quite sure what you're gaining here. Hope that helps

Comment: this will look something like:
Output: [2, 5]
Output: [3, 6]
Output: [1, 5]
Output: [3, 1]
Output: [1, 6]
Output: [2, 1]

Is there a way to be like: Output: [[2,5],[2,1],[1,0]] ?

Comment: TJReinert is right here. It seems like what you really want is a string representation of your graph

Comment: simple print will return: [[], [[I@1fb3ebeb, [I@548c4f57], [[I@1218025c, [I@816f27d], [[I@87aac27, [I@3e3abc88]]

Comment: @sean You've gone through both lists, but you still need to print out the arrays explicitly.